# Why is Ruby on Rails executing `SELECT 1 AS one` queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting into a project in Ruby on Rails currently, which I don't really have any experience in. Now, we're running into some performance problems that I think are related to executing too many queries.

We have a `Service` model that we set in our controller as follows:

```
@services = Service.includes(:points).with_points
```

The `with_points` scope is defined in the service as such:

```
scope :with_points, -> { joins(:points).where.not(points: []).distinct }
```

(I think the where clause is not needed here, but that's probably not relevant to the question.)

Then in the view, we're using the fetched *services*, with linked *points*, as follows:

```
<% @services.each do |s| %>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 serviceDiv" data-rating="<%= s.service_ratings %>" >
        <% if s.service_ratings == "A" %>
            <% grade = "rating-a" %>
                <!-- etc. -->
```

Now, as far as I've seen when researching around, this is a relatively normal pattern when trying to list all rows from a table. However, when I look at the logs, it looks like a separate query is executed for every *service*?

```
# This query is what I'd expect:
SQL (1.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "services"."id" # etc, etc
# But then we also get one of these for every service
Service Exists (1.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "services" WHERE "services"."name" = $1 AND ("services"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3
# And quite a few of these for every service:
CACHE Service Exists (0.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "services" WHERE "services"."name" = $1 AND ("services"."id" != $2) LIMIT $3
```

Now, my hunch is that those "Service Exists" lines are bad news. What are they, and where are they coming from? Is there anything else that's relevant that I'm missing here?

Comment: What's in the block passed to `each`?

Comment: Some HTML that uses `s` - I've updated the question with a short snippet. (There's more, but this happens even without that.)

Comment: What kind of relation exists between Service and Point? Can you share your models code?

Comment: Ok, I have no idea what happens here, but this gem might help you trace this issue:
https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace
BTW I understand `service_ratings` is just a column in `services` table?

Comment: @hernanvicente Service has many points, code here: https://github.com/tosdr/phoenix/blob/master/app/models/service.rb

Comment: @MarekLipka That's a good question, it appears that `service_ratings` is a property computed in the model itself. I'll take a look at QueryTrace, let's see if I can get that working :)

Comment: @MarekLipka I've got a strong hunch that you directed me to the solution! `service_ratings` calls `self.update_attributes`, which appears to actually update the row in the database. That could be optimised to not run every time we select data, I'd think :)

Answer (score 2):

After @MarekLipka's pointers in the comments on this question, I managed to find the source of the problem. Not sure how many people will run into this setup in the future, but I'll share it just in case.

The clue was in our accessing `s.service_ratings` which was not, in fact, a column in the database. [ActiveRecord Query Trace](https://github.com/ruckus/active-record-query-trace) pointed to the source of all those queries being a reference to `s.service_ratings` in the view, which was a red flag.

`service_ratings` was actually a method (assuming I'm using the correct terminology here) on the `Service` model that, apart from returning a value based on a calculation on several of the model's properties, *also* called `self.update_attributes` to actually store that value in the database. This meant that every time we retrieved this model's data in order to display it, we also ran another query to save that value to the database - often redundantly.

In other words, the solution for us now is to either run the calculation at some other point of time and store it in the database once, or recalculate it every time we need it and not store it at all.